# Manipulate Object to group based on Array Object List

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I'm trying to find a way to convert this list of objects based on the group array. The tricky part I've found is iterating through the group Array and applying the object to more than one place if there are multiple groups.

I'm also trying to ignore any group that does not belong to anything. I've tried using the reduce function but I cannot get the iteration through the group array.

```
  let cars = 
    [
      {
        "group":[],
        "name": "All Makes",
        "code": ""
      },
      {
        "group":["Group A"],
        "name": "BMW",
        "code": "X821"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B"],
        "name": "Audi",
        "code": "B216"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B"],
        "name": "Ford",
        "code": "P385"    
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B", "Group C"],
        "name": "Mercedes",
        "code": "H801"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group C"],
        "name": "Honda",
        "code": "C213"
      }
    ]
```

To become this:

```
[
    {
      "group": "Group A",
      "cars": [
         {
           name: "BMW",
           code: "X821"
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "Group B",
      "cars": [
         {
           name: "Audi",
           code: "B216"
         },
         {
           name: "Ford",
           code: "P385"
         },
         {
           name: "Mercedes",
           code: "H801"
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "Group C",
      "cars": [
         {
           name: "Mercedes",
           code: "H801"
         },
         {
           name: "Honda",
           code: "C213"
         }
      ]
    }

]
```

I've already tried using reduce to accomplish this but it doesn't quite get the desired affect.

```
const res = cars.reduce((acc, {group, ...r}) => {
  group.forEach(key => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || []).concat({...r}); 
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string keys on arrays doesn't work quite well, that's what objects are for, then use `Object.values` to get the array out of it. Also you want to put objects and not arrays in there:

```
 const res = Object.values(cars.reduce((acc, {group, ...r}) => {
    group.forEach(key => {
      (acc[key] = (acc[key] || { group, cars: [] })).cars.push(r);
    });
    return acc;
 }, {}));
```

I'd write it this way:

```
  const byGroup = new Map();

  for(const { group, ...rest } of cars) {
     if(!byGroup.has(group))
       byGroup.set(group, { group, cars: [] });
     byGroup.get(group).cars.push(rest);
  }

  const result = [...byGroup.values()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take an object as accumulator and then map the entries fro getting the wanted result.

```js
 let cars = [{ group: [], name: "All Makes", code: "" }, { group: ["Group A"], name: "BMW", code: "X821" }, { group: ["Group B"], name: "Audi", code: "B216" }, { group: ["Group B"], name: "Ford", code: "P385" }, { group: ["Group B", "Group C"], name: "Mercedes", code: "H801" }, { group: ["Group C"], name: "Honda", code: "C213" }],
    result = Object
        .entries(cars.reduce((acc, { group, ...r }) => {
            group.forEach(key => acc[key] = (acc[key] || []).concat({...r}));
            return acc;
         }, {}))
        .map(([group, cars]) => ({ group, cars }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```